# How do you effectively fight when armatized with a wind seraph?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

I've gotten pretty far in the game, and gotten pretty good at fighting as Sorey, and when fighting while armatized as fire, water, or earth. I understand their strengths and weaknesses.

However, when armatized with a wind seraph, it honestly feels like it's worse than just letting the wind seraph AI do its thing alone, as far as damage output is concerned. I use it only to heal, then pop back out into normal form to continue fighting. I feel like I'm missing something.

The seraphic artes in wind form are awkward to use. The base one doesn't even do damage, and the next two require you to be in very, very close range (which means they usually get interrupted, even when comboing into them to speed up the cast time) and do less damage than any of the 3 other elemental seraphic artes.

The hidden artes in wind form are also seemingly inferior to other elemental counterparts. There isn't much AoE, and what AoE exists requires the enemies to be very close, which is difficult because enemies don't always stand still. I find myself just dancing around uselessly most of the time I'm armatized as wind.

How can I effectively use this form in combat? Is it actually just weaker than the others? Does it fill some niche I haven't encountered or realized?

Answer (score 2):

The wind armatization is not objectively weaker than the other three... but it probably is.

Here is what I mean.

Both Hidden and Seraphic artes scale off Arte Attack, not regular Attack. The game sets up your wind seraph to be your third physical attacker, meaning unless you put a bunch of effort in to increase his Arte Attack (or one of your human's Arte Attack), you will be doing LESS damage while armatized with him than you would be seperate. Add to this the awkwardness of the wind armtization hidden arts and the whole form seems very underpowerd.

Wind armatization gets slightly better as you fill out your hidden artes, The latter ones let you do more aoe and move forward when attacking. But by this time your other forms have also improved to the point where Water and Fire armatizations can perma stagger most enemies (including bosses!) because of their long duration seraphic artes.

In the end there I found very little reason to use the wind armatization outside of the gorgon fights.